# Haskell create list from newtype data

Tags: haskell, matrix, newtype

This is a homework assignment first off.  We are given a newtype Matrix which is the professor's implementation of an abstract Matrix.  My main issue is how do you create a list of type Matrix.  The first function fillWith which I need to implement takes a tuple which is (number of rows, number of columns) of the matrix to create and the data to place at each index.

```
module Matrix (Matrix, fillWith, fromRule, numRows, numColumns, 
           at, mtranspose, mmap, add, mult) 
where

-- newtype is like "data", but has some efficiency advantages
newtype Matrix a = Mat ((Int,Int),(Int,Int) -> a)

--fillWith   :: (Int,Int) -> a -> (Matrix a)
--fillWith ix val = Mat ((, 


--trying to create a row of type Matrix
row_matrix :: [a] -> Matrix a
row_matrix ls = Mat ((1, length ls), (\x y -> if x > 1 then undefined else ls !! (y-1)))
```

Comment: This definition of `Matrix` is terrible. You can tell your professor I said so. Unidiomatic, and I dispute the claims of efficiency wins compared to the merely slightly strange `data Matrix a = Mat { width, height :: Int, members :: (Int, Int) -> a }`.

Comment: You might want to ask a question about that newtype vs. data claim _with_ _the_ _specific_ _definition_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just missing some parens and a comma:

```
row_matrix ls = Mat ((1, length ls), (\(x,y) -> if x > 1 then undefined else ls !! (y-1)))
                                       ^-^-^--- add these
```

`Mat` is a tuple where:

- the first element is itself a tuple, and
- the second element is a function taking a *tuple* to a value of type a

You may always use a `where` or `let` clause to simplify the construction of values, e.g.:

```
row_matrix as = Mat (bounds, accessor)
  where bounds = (1, length as)
        accessor (i,j) = if i > 1 then undefined else as !! (j-1)
```

Using a `where` clause makes the code a lot more readable.

To implement `fillWith` I would follow the same recipe:

```
fillWith bounds val = Mat (bounds, accessor)
  where accessor (i,j) = ???
```

I think it's obvious now what the ??? should be.

Comment: basically, but check your answer with the compiler; there are lots of ways of writing it, e.g. `accessor (i,j) = val` or `accessor = \(i,j) -> val` or `accessor = const val`